# postfix host smtp.gmail.com said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i44-v6sm1465721wri.17 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I am trying to configure php sendmail postfix. So far I am unable to get my postfix working to send an email.

Wherever I send an email through php I get this error

postfix host smtp.gmail.com said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i44-v6sm1465721wri.17 - gsmtp     (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

This is what u get from postconf -n

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /opt/local/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /opt/local/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /opt/local/var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/opt/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_privs = nobody
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = _postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mailq_path = /opt/local/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /opt/local/share/man
meta_directory = /opt/local/etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
myhostname = localhost
myorigin = localhost
newaliases_path = /opt/local/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /opt/local/var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /opt/local/share/postfix/readme
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
sample_directory = /opt/local/share/postfix/sample
sendmail_path = /opt/local/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
shlib_directory = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/opt/local/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I got the following permission

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1424 17 Apr 14:05 cacert.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin     58 18 Apr 12:14 sasl_passwd
```

I also tried smtp_tls_security_level = may with no luck
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this same problem on Sierra (10.12).

Comment: I solved my problem on Sierra by upgrading to High Sierra,